# asterisk: error while loading shared libraries: libasteriskssl.so.1

Tags: linux, ubuntu, symbolic-link, asterisk, shared-libraries

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 and followed the instructions to install asterisk from this link 
[Ubuntu 14.04 Asterisk server installation](https://gist.github.com/weilant/ec4a3e9e65504e7e67a0873dca353871)

All worked well until I run asterisk and get a shared lib error.

```
asterisk: error while loading shared libraries: libasteriskssl.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

further examining of the dynamically linked lib using "ldd"...

```
$ldd /usr/sbin/asterisk
linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fff2d50a000)
libasteriskssl.so.1 => not found
libxml2.so.2 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxml2.so.2 (0x00007f7315902000)
...
```

...reveals that the symlink is missing.
I know how to create a symlink but the question is from where do I create the link?

Answer (score 2):

Found the answer in this link

https://community.asterisk.org/t/asterisk-does-not-start/74617

> Please run
>
> find / -name libasteriskssl.so.1 -print
>
> to locate your library and then check if it is one of the directories
>   listed in /etc/ld.so.conf
>
> If not, add it and run “ldconfig -v”
>
> if yes, try just running “ldconfig -v” and check if the library is now
>   cached